# something like logmein that will let me login to a remote ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-control, logmein

I am looking for something like logmein but my target machine is Ubuntu 8.04.

I.e. I want to easily log in from any place in the internet to my ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

Use Teamviewer. If you are a commercial user, try GoSupportNow (http://www.gosupportnow.com). It works on Linux with Wine and costs just $19.95 per month.

Comment: I second the vote for teamviewer if you are in need of a GUI login to any linux system.  If you just need access to the command prompt, the obviously use SSHd on then Linux side and Putty as your client.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to LogMeIn is [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php):

> TightVNC is a free remote control
>   software package. With TightVNC, you
>   can see the desktop of a remote
>   machine and control it with your local
>   mouse and keyboard, just like you
>   would do it sitting in the front of
>   that computer. TightVNC is:
>
> - free for both personal and commercial
>     usage, with full source code available
>     (GPL-licensed);
> - useful in remote
>     administration, remote customer
>     support, education, and for many other
>     purposes;
> - cross-platform, available
>     for Windows and **Unix**, compatible with
>     other VNC software.

It's not as convenient as LogMeIn, since you need the target PCs IP address, but it's good enough in most cirmcumstances.

Comment: or any VNC client will work as well.  note the VNC server software to use depends on what you want -- just a login on the remote server (Xvnc/vncserver/tightvncserver), or connecting/controlling an existing X session (x11vnc, vino, etc).

Comment: @~quack You're right, basically any VNC client should work. It's a universal solution; I use VNC to connect from an iPod Touch to a PC running Windows 7.

Comment: There are many case. Where PC needs plug-n-play. And TECH guy need plug-n-play remote connection. TightVNC, RealVNC, X11vnc, any VNC is not having this feature to do.

Answer (score 0):

For command line you could use ssh or [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) depending on whether you are logging in from a Linux or Windows machine.

For a graphical login I use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) or even Windows' Remote Desktop (this will need the [server](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/) installing on the Ubuntu, I would imagine that the servers for the other protocols are part of the standard install).

Comment: maybe for server installs.  ubuntu desktop supplies Vino for VNC capability, but doesn't include ssh-server in a default install.